# Using vue.js transition tags in Shopify liquid templates

Tags: vue.js, shopify, liquid

It appears that Shopify is removing the transition tag:

```
<transition name="fade"> ... </transition>
```

In addition, when I wrap my v-for loop in the transition it only renders the first one then stops. No errors in the console or Vue inspector.

Are there any possible work arounds for animating without these or getting them to parse in liquid?

To clarify I need to transition a sortable group of products that I'm using the filter method on to toggle.

```
v-for="product in filteredProducts"
```

Then my filter:

```
filteredProducts: function() {
  var parent = this;

  return parent.products.filter(function (product) {

    if(parent.selected.length == 0) {
      return product;
    } else {

      console.log(product.id);

      for (var i = parent.selected.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(parent.selected[i].products.includes(product.id)) {
          return product;
        }
      }

    }

  });

},
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue wasn't with Shopify at all, but rather the v-bind:key attribute missing on v-for in order to work with a transition group.

```
<div v-for="product in filteredProducts" v-if="product.available" v-bind:key="product">
```

Prior to that everything nested in the transition-group was being removed, and  would only work for the first item.